# ZF2 get values from database into form class

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2, suppose I have a `Select` in the form:

```
    $this->add([
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'someName',
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'some-id',
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Some Label',
            'value_options' => [
                '1' => 'type 1',
                '2' => 'type 2',
                '3' => 'type 3',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

How can I put the values 'type 1', 'type 2', 'type 3', etc. from a database query into `value_options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By registering a custom select element with the form element manager, you can use a factory to load the required form options.

```
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

class TypeSelectFactory
{
    public function __invoke(FormElementManager $formElementManager)
    {
        $select = new \Zend\Form\Element\Select('type');
        $select->setAttributes(]
            'id' => 'some-id',
        ]);
        $select->setOptions([
            'label' => 'Some Label',
        ]);

        $serviceManager = formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $typeService  = $serviceManager->get('Some\\Service\\That\\Executes\\Queries');

        // getTypesAsArray returns the expected value options array 
        $valueOptions = $typeService->getTypesAsArray();

        $select->setValueOptions($valueOptions);

        return $select;
    }
}
```

And the required configuration for `module.config.php`.

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        'MyModule\\Form\\Element\\TypeSelect'
            => 'MyModule\\Form\\Element\\TypeSelectFactory',
    ]
],
```

You can then use `MyModule\\Form\\Element\\TypeSelect` as the `type` value when adding the element to a form.

Also make sure to read the [documentation regarding custom form elements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements); this describes how to use the form element manager correctly, essential for the above to work.

Comment: man, you rock! read a coupla other answers of yours on SO. you're great!

Comment: just one note: in the form, i need to add this element into `public function init()` as the link to the zend docs says.

Comment: could you just advise, how to pass an additional parameter (`$id`) to `TypeSelectFactory`'s `$typeService  = $serviceManager->get('Some\\Service\\That\\Executes\\Queries');`?