# ZF2 add elemets to form on the fly from database

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I get the form from the controller factory like this:

```
class SomeControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function CreateService(SeviceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $realServiceLocator   = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        // other things from service manager
        $registrationForm = $realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager')
            ->get('Path\To\My\Form\RegistrationForm');
    }
    return new SomeController(
        // controller dependencies, including $registrationForm
    );
}
```

In the `RegistrationForm`, I have `MultiCheckBox`:

```
    $this->add([
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckBox',
        'name' => 'partyRoleIds',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Отношение',
            'value_options' => [
                [
                    'value' => '1',
                    'label' => 'client',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => '2',
                    'label' => 'prospect'],
                [
                    'value' => '6',
                    'label' => 'contractor',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

I want to populate `value_options` from a db query that returns an array like `[1 => 'client', 2 => 'prospect'...]`. Populating is not an problem, but I don't know how to pass this array as a dependency into the `RegistrationForm` because in the call `$registrationForm = $realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get('Path\To\My\Form\RegistrationForm');`, I don't have any place to add the dependency.

How could I do this?

PS: rewritten the question, please forgive my initial brevity.

Comment: And what is the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Rizier123, maybe it's stupid, but i don't know how to pass this array into the form in a nice way. i'm calling the form from the controller with the factory controller. in the factory controller, i'm using service manager to get the form like this: `$realServiceLocator->get('FormElementManager')
            ->get('Path\To\My\Form\RegistrationForm');`, and in this way, i don't know how to pass the array into the `RegistrationForm`.

Comment: @Rizier123, updated the OP.

Comment: Much better question after the edit.

Comment: The controller factory should not be responsible for loading the form element's dependencies. [The answer I provided to your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975766/zf2-get-values-from-database-into-form-class/35977320#35977320) would provide the same solution, in this case you would have a factory for the MultiCheckBox element.

Comment: @AlexP, yeah, i understood that already because of your answer to my last question. could i ask you please to have a look at this if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36107490/4685379. in any case, buddy, you're awesome! i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form classes you add the method :

```
public function setValueOptions($element, array $values_options)
{
    $e = $this->get($element);
    $e->setValueOptions($values_options);
    return $this;
}
```

In your controller, if your form is $registrationForm you write :

```
$registrationForm->setValueOptions('partyRoleIds', $valueOptions);
```

where $valueOptions is an array like your sample.

Comment: as AlexP suggested in the comments to the question, the better way is to have a factory that creates this element, and this factory will load its dependencies by itself. but i accept your answer as a reasonable workaround. :-)