# ZF2, pass variable to custom element from controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

In ZF2, I have a custom form element factory. It creates a custom `MultiCheckbox` and fills the checkbox values and labels from a db query.

```
class MyMultiCheckboxFactory
{
    public function __invoke(FormElementManager $formElementManager)
    {
        $multiCheck = new \Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox();

        $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $mapper = $serviceManager->get('Path\To\Mapper\To\Query\DB');
        $descriptions = $mapper->findDescriptions($id);

        // some processing to prepare $value_options array

        $multiCheck->setOptions([
            'label' => 'blah-blah',
            'value_options' => $value_options
        ]);

        return $multiCheck;
    }
}
```

My problem is as follows. The method `findDescriptions($id)` depends on the `$id` which I can get from the route. But when I use `MyMultiCheckbox` in the form like this:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->add([
        'type' => 'Path\To\MyMultiCheckbox',
        'name' => 'someName'
    ]);
}
```

I don't know how to pass the `$id` into the `MyMultiCheckbox`.

Could anyone help pleeeeeeeeeease?

Comment: sorry for Russian but. Сорри куда передать то надо? и я так понимаю есть шаблон для этого елемента? when you want passed this variable in you template for custom element.

Comment: @Naumov, hey, there isn't a view script attached to this element (if that's what you mean by a template ;-) ). the form generates this element and all others automatically. my point is to pass this bloody `id` into this custom element so that i don't have to tweak neither the form, nor the view script later.

Comment: adding in `value_options['attributes'] => array('id' => 'yourId')` do not get result as in documentation http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.element.multicheckbox.html

Comment: oh no, my friend, i think i wasn't clear enough in my original post. problem is that this `id` isn't supposed to be the attribute of the form element. it's another id based on which i run the query against the database, process the result, and create `$value_options` array. this `id` comes from the route of the controller. or did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry I don't correct understand you question. You have route `yoursite/controller/action/id/12` you can get this id by Request class for example http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.http.request.html

Comment: давай на русском )). смотри, у меня есть фактори, который (если я его вызову через ServiceManager), выдаёт мне мой элемент. этот элемент -- multicheckbox. мне нужно в этот элемент закинуть айдиху из раута (т.е. из контроллера). в этом элементе я использую айдиху из раута, чтобы запросить базу данных. от базы данных, получаю array, который использую, чтобы создать `$value_options` array в этом элементе. проблема в том, что если использовать стандартное создание элементов в форме (`$this->add(['type' => 'Path\To\MyMultiCheckbox']);`), я не знаю, как вбросить сюда айдиху.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106817/discussion-between-dima-dz-and-naumov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the id via the 'route match' instance *inside* the factory.

```
$event = $serviceManager->get('Application')->getMvcEvent();
$id = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id', false);

if (empty($id)) {
   throw new ServiceNotCreatedException('id not set!');
}

$descriptions = $mapper->findDescriptions($id);
```

Comment: man, god bless your fingers that type and your brain that helps. thanks so damn much!